# Converter String para MD5 com Flutter

Tags: criptografia, md5, flutter

Tenho uma aplicação em Flutter,e estou tentando converter minha Password para MD5 na tela de login, encontrei alguns outros métodos porém nenhum me serviu.
Estou tentando usar `final md5 = new MD5._()` para converter `final String password;`, mas sem sucesso.
Teria alguma outra forma de criptografar a String usando o pacote `Crypto` do Flutter?

Comment: Olá, antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a lib [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto). Ela possui suporte para os algoritmos de hash:

- SHA-1
- SHA-256
- MD5
- HMAC (i.e. HMAC-MD5, HMAC-SHA1, HMAC-SHA256)

Basta adicionar no seu `pubspec.yaml`:

```
crypto: ^2.0.6
```

Importa os pacotes:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
```

E agora o código:

```dart
String textToMd5 (String text) {
  return md5.convert(utf8.encode(text)).toString();
}
```

O `md5.convert` recebe uma lista de int, por isso precisamos codificar a string primeiramente com o `utf8.encode`.

No link da lib você encontra exemplos com outros hashs.

Comment: Muito obrigado Julio, funcionou corretamente assim. Apenas chamei o textToMd5 no meu   `Map toMap() {
                                   var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                                     map["password"] = textToMd5(password);
                                     return map;
                                     }`

Comment: Show! Só uma dica, não use a palavra reservada 'new' para criação dos objetos, a partir do Dart 2 ela se tornou opcional, e agora é um 'padrão' da comunidade não utilizá-la. Facilita a leitura do código.

Comment: Ótimo, Obrigado pela dica, irei por em prática de agora em diante.